# File already opened by other process

Tags: c#, .net, excel, file, streamreader

I have the following code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var filename = "0f351ee0-0e7b-488b-80c5-db5da81f4bb5";
            Do_forecast(filename);
        }

private static void Do_forecast(string file_guid)
        {
            string tempFilePath = Path.GetTempPath();

            string infile = file_guid + ".xlsx";
            string outfile = file_guid + "_output.xlsx";
            string local_in_file_path = Path.Combine(tempFilePath, infile);
            string local_out_file_path = Path.Combine(tempFilePath, outfile);

            Download_FromBlob(infile, CONTAINER_NAME, local_in_file_path);
            Start_forecast(local_in_file_path);
        }

private static void Start_forecast(string file_path)
        {
            WorkBook workbook = WorkBook.Load(file_path); //ERROR OCCURS
            WorkSheet sheet = workbook.WorkSheets.First();
            Console.WriteLine(sheet["A2"]);
        }
private static void Download_FromBlob(string filetoDownload, string azure_ContainerName, string path)
        {
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Start downloading");

                CloudStorageAccount mycloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CONNECTION_STRING);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = mycloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(azure_ContainerName);
                CloudBlockBlob cloudBlockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filetoDownload);

                
                    // provide the file download location below            
                    Stream file = File.OpenWrite(path);

                    cloudBlockBlob.DownloadToStream(file);
                   
                

                Console.WriteLine("Download completed!");

            }
        }
```

So a excel file in my tempf folder gets created and filled with the data from the Blob Storage. Now I want to see the data from the Excel file, but always an error occurs because the file is still used by a previous process in the code.
How and where can I close the connections to the file?
I have already to try it with Streamreaderobject.ReadtoEnd(), but with that I'm always getting the same error.

Comment: `Stream file = ...` should be better transformed in a `using(Stream stream = File.OpenWrite(path)) { /* ... do stuff with stream */ }  ` --> read about [using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement), it automatically closes the stream at the end } and therefore unlocks the file at path.

Comment: Problem is solved, thanks :)